# Unable to write keys.dev.pub to: /home/ubuntu/.composer

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, vagrant, key, composer-php

I'm following the instructions to install composer ([found here](https://getcomposer.org/download/](https://getcomposer.org/download/)). I just ran the line `php composer-setup.php` and the terminal returned:

```
All settings correct for using Composer
Unable to write keys.dev.pub to: /home/ubuntu/.composer
```

I'm installing into a Ubuntu VM in Vagrant.

Comment: looks like a permission issue

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It can happen when you have a previous installation of composer not completely removed or if you are running the installer with a user different to the owner of `.composer` folder.

You can rename the old folder (to have a backup) and then try again:

```
mv ~/.composer ~/.composer.old
```

This is less risky than executing something unknown with sudo.

Comment: Marked this as the actual answer since it fixes the issue most of the time, and doesn't require root permissions. Running stuff as `sudo` can get new users into trouble pretty quickly - moving this to the top to hopefully stop that from happening.

Comment: In my case `mv ~/.config/composer/ ~/.config/composer.old/`

Answer (score 43):

While installing the Composer in your Project Directory you may Get this error.
Im Using the Ubuntu 16,While installing i faced the Same Issue

---

### All settings correct for using Composer Unable to write keys.dev.pub to: /home/ubuntu/.composer

> Step 1: just go to your Project Directory and run a Command

```
sudo su
```

> Step 2: then Try to install the Composer using The Following Command

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Comment: `sudo` (as per accepted answer) did not work for me, while `sudo su`, as per [sunil KV](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5255819/sunil-kv)'s suggestion, actually fixed the issue

Comment: The whole point of installing composer in your project directory is that it should NOT recommend superuser privileges.

Comment: This is a bad answer, possibly just outdated. You should not be installing composer as `root`, which is exactly what this would be doing. You should fix the file permissions on `/home/ubuntu/.composer` and run anything to do with composer as the `ubuntu` user.

Comment: I've removed this as the actual answer. As _many_ other users have stated, running stuff as `sudo` is dangerous, and Composer is designed to be installed _without_ the need of `sudo`.

Answer (score 6):

try

```
sudo apt-get install composer
```

Answer (score 5):

if you have installed composer using `sudo`, or with a user different to the owner of .composer folder, as mentioned by @PhoneixS

**Check** if this is the case, by running:

```
ls -al ~/.composer
```

which may return

```
ls -al .composer 
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May  1 15:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 53 user-name  user-group  4096 May  1 15:07 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  799 May  1 15:04 keys.dev.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  799 May  1 15:04 keys.tags.pub
```

**Then**:

- if the owner of .composer is the root user, running the
  command with `sudo`, as fallow  `sudo php composer-setup.php` ,will fix the issue
- if the owner is root but you don't want to have to run composer as root, then you can change the owner-user:owner-group of .composer to the current user as follow: `sudo chown -R owner-user:owner-group ~/.composer`
- if the owner of .composer is the a different user than user-name, then you can run the command as that specific user, using `su`

Comment: Perfect answer !

Comment: Good explanation and alternatives on how to diagnose and solve the problem. I would recommend putting the second option (change the username) first, as I think it's the best option.

Answer (score 4):

It seems permission issue with your current user. You may try with this.

```sh
sudo chown $USER -R /home/$USER/.composer
```

NB: $USER always refer to the current user in Linux type system.